# Grouping Lines from .txt File

Tags: java, text

version: jre1.8.0 +

I have a very simple .txt file with item names, each item on it's own line. I want to print the entire list while separating every four items into it's own "group." The items do not need to be sorted, they're already in the correct order.

The code I have so far is:

```
try {
    BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("items.txt"));
    String lineText = null;
    while ((lineText = lineReader.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(lineText);
}
```

When every four lines are printed it would look something like this:

```
Toast
Milk
Eggs
Cheese
--
Bacon
Orange Juice
Banana
Apple
```

My primary problem is grouping every 4 items. I've had no issue simply reading and printing the entire file.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: have you a begin of code ?
if no you should look at  the **BufferedReader** Class (and if you could have the document in only one string like that "Toast Milk Egs Cheese Bacon OrangeJuice Banana Apple" look at **StringTokenizer** Class)

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far ?

Comment: try {
   BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("items.txt"));
   String lineText = null;

   while ((lineText = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(lineText);
   }
So far I can print the whole list but I can't figure out how to group them every 4 items.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide your code so others see it at first glance instead of posting it in the comments.

Comment: Step 1 - Add a counter that you can increment in the main loop. Step 2 - If the counter has reached a certain value, reset it and print out your dashes. Step 3 - Profit.